# How does JSON get converted from a string to an object?

Tags: javascript, json

Behind the scenes, is JSON created using `eval`?

If not, how does the string `'{"val1":1,"val2":2}'` get turned into an object where `.val1 == 1` and `.val2 == 2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is usually converted into a JavaScript object using a JSON parser. Browsers nowadays come with one which can be accessed via [the `parse` method of the `JSON` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). The traditional pollyfill is [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

That string, however, is not JSON and cannot be parsed with a JSON parser.

Comment: @Quentin - Line 471 of crockford's code for json (source: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js ) reads `j = eval('(' + text + ')');` JSON.parse, from your documentation linked, reads: `parse: function (sJSON) { return eval("(" + sJSON + ")"); },`

Comment: @TravisJ — Those are both pollyfills for browsers that don't have built in JSON parsers. json2.js is safer, it tests to make sure the string is JSON before evaling it.

Comment: @Quentin - I see, I wasn't sure if the dot notation could be used if the object was constructed from a parsing. This works though: `var obj = {};
    obj["val1"] = 1;
    console.log(obj.val1);` so it must be possible for the parser to construct the json through a similar method.

Answer (score 0):

try this

var obj = `JSON.parse(string);`

or this is another way

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"val1\":\"1\",\"val2\":\"2\"}");
```